# Storage partition doesn't have the right permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a dual boot setup on my PC, Windows and Ubuntu. I have 3 main partitions 100GB for Windows, 100GB for Ubuntu and ~800GB as a common storage partition. On Windows everything works fine, on Ubuntu though certain programs, namely my browser, are not able to access the partition throwing errors similar to "permission denied". Even from the command line I don't have execute permission.
I followed this tutorial https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/

I modified /etc/fstab as shown in the tutorial, adding the line:

```
UUID=01D5B8E922E76B20 /media/storage/    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0
```

Another problem I'm experiencing is, when trying to delete a file: ' "file.ext" can't be put in trash. Do you want to delete it immediately? '

Comment: How do you `mount` the filesystem exactly? Is it NTFS? Are you aware of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1250132/432690)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I've edited the question as you asked

Comment: This answer may help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511936/336403

Answer (score 1):

Windows Fast Startup is a problem when using NTFS volumes in multi-boot, since it will
set all volumes to read-only when Windows is shutdown.

I would suggest:

- Boot with Windows
- Run `chkdsk` to ensure that the disk is good
- Run *Power Options*
- Click *Choose what the power buttons do*
- Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable*
- Click "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" so that the check-mark disappears
- Click *Save changes*
- Shutdown Windows and try Linux again.

Comment: It doesn't show any fast startup option, I have a fresh install of Windows 10 Home

Comment: Strange, as this is the default.

Comment: I looked up online and found this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/power-option-does-not-show-turn-on-fast-startup/bab0ecd6-7efc-4181-a1c9-e6d3c5d72c2c

Comment: I didn't understand it wasn't showing at all - I thought you meant it was already off. You might in addition to the link you found, and if my answer doesn't solve the problem, try the command `powercfg /hibernate off`.

Comment: Yes, the advanced options as "Change settings that are currently unavailable" are not so trivial to find in win 10 (can't believe Microsoft messed it up creating a parallel control panel). You may want to open manually the Control Panel and then use the search tool in the top right corner of the screen.